# MYSQL: how to automatically drop rows in a table that are depending on a record in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have very little experience with mysql, so please forgive my question.

I have two tables, one containing lessons, as follows:

```
id  title   type    language    level
```

And another containing the sections:

```
lesson_id   title   content duration
```

Each lesson has 0 or several sections.

Now I have a function in my web page that allows me to delete a lesson.

1 - How can I make the sections *dependant* on the lesson record?

I want that by deleting the lesson record the database automatically knows that it has to delete all the sections fields that belongs to that lesson.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alter your Section Table and define lesson_id as a Foreign Key referencing Lesson Table and define it as On Delete Cascade.

```
ALTER TABLE sections
ADD FOREIGN KEY fk_lesson(lesson_id)
REFERENCES lessons(id)
ON DELETE cascade;
```

This way when you delete a row from Lesson Table all the rows from the Sections Table.

Comment: I have to execute this sql statement only once, right?

Comment: Yes,  ideally you should have defined it when you created the table.  This command just alters the table and need to run only once.

Answer (score 0):

You could delete from  both the tables using a single query

Assuminng you want delete the rows related  to the lessons id  = your_value

try using a join

```
    delete l, s
    from lessons l
    inner join section s on s.lesson_id  = l.id 
    where l.id = your_value
```